Firebase Auth - SignIn with Google success even if accessToken is invalid
I have a question about the Google SSO and FirebaseAuth library. I have this code
class GoogleAuthService {
    
    func signIn(completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        guard let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene else { return }
        guard let rootViewController = windowScene.windows.first?.rootViewController else { return }
        let generalError = NSError(domain: "google_signin_error", code: -1)
        
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(withPresenting: rootViewController) { result, error in
            if let error = error {
                completion(error)
                return
            }
            
            guard let user = result?.user,
                  let idToken = user.idToken?.tokenString else {
                completion(generalError)
                return
            }
            
            let accessToken = user.accessToken.tokenString
            let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken, accessToken: "invalid")
            print("Before SSO", Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)
            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { authResult, error in
                print("After SSO", Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)
                completion(error)
            }
        }
    }
}

When I go through the flow and pass credentials with accessToken "invalid", I am still able to log in successfully.
From the debug prints that I have, this is the output.
Before SSO nil
After SSO Optional("userId")

Is it a bug in the library or something? Or is it intentional? I couldn't find any documents or materials explaining this behaviour.
Versions:

Min. target - iOS 17
googlesignin-ios v7.1.0
firebase-ios-sdk v10.28.1

Thanks a lot.
